# Did you initially thought "comparable" was pronounced as "com-pair-able"?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

And were you surprised to learn it pronounced as "com-pra-ble"?

Answer (score -1):

## It is "kom-puh-ruh-ble"

You are saying that the pronunciation should be/already is, "com-pra-ble"? But, that pronunciation is a bit difficult, isn't it? It's better to pronounce it as, "**kom-puh-ruh-ble**". Yeah, that's what they pronounce this word in British English (and also Indian English).

But, it was never, EVER pronounced as "com-pair-able"! That is the worst way to pronounce this word.
Mind those little, yet ***significant*** "h" in the middle of the pronunciations. Those are the keys to improved pronunciation.

And, mind ***carefully***. Give considerable stress to the first "h". But, give the second an insignificant stress.

Comment: "that pronunciation is a bit difficult, isn't it?"...No, it isn't.

Comment: Well, usually in these cases, I tell people to suit themselves. But, in your case, I can see that you are seriously misinformed about the pronunciation.

Comment: As a British English speaker I pronounce it exactly as it is written. That is "com-par-a-ble', I see no need for the aitches.